# Npm remover pastas de teste para a produção

Tags: node.js, npm

**npm prune --production** remove os pacotes do devDependencies. Existe alguma forma de ele também apagar as pastas do projeto que eu não quero na produção, como a minha pasta "spec", de testes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O padrão que utilizo para remover a pasta de testes para produção é adicionar a pasta `tests` ao arquivo .gitignore nas branchs específicas para deploy.

Comment: É exatamente o que eu estava procurando. Na verdade, isso não resolve para o comando npm prune --production. Pelo que eu testei, ele mantém as pastas do .npmignore mesmo depois de executar o comando. Mas isso resolve para o meu repositório npm. Ele não baixa os arquivos do .npmignore quando executo o npm install